# Java ActionListener not listening to event

Tags: java, events, event-handling, awt

anyone can tell why the class OpenMenuListener doesnt send a feedback when i click the open button in my Gui ? The erase button works though. It sends me a feedback.  I'm exausted.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class DrawingApplication extends JFrame {

    JComponent drawingArea;

    class EraseButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Clicked erase");
        }
    }

    class OpenMenuListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Clicked open");
    }
    }
        public DrawingApplication() {
        JPanel frame = new JPanel();
        add(frame);
        // panel1.add( new JButton(Figuur),BorderLayout.CENTER);

        drawingArea = new JLabel();
        // label1.add(drawingArea);
        frame.add(drawingArea);

        // Creates a menubar for a JFrame
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        // Add the menubar to the frame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);


        JMenu open = new JMenu("Open");
        fileMenu.add(open);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        JMenu save = new JMenu("Save");
        fileMenu.add(save);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        JMenu close  =new JMenu("Close");
        fileMenu.add(close);
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

        menuBar.add(helpMenu);
        helpMenu.add(new JMenu("Info"));

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, frame);
        frame.add(new JLabel("figuurkeuze"));
        frame.add(panel2);
        setVisible(true);

        JRadioButton rectButton = new JRadioButton("Rectangle");
        JRadioButton triangleButton = new JRadioButton("Triangle");
        JRadioButton circleButton = new JRadioButton("Circle");
        frame.add(rectButton);
        frame.add(triangleButton);
        frame.add(circleButton);

        JButton erase = new JButton("Erase");
        frame.add(erase);

        EraseButtonListener eraselistener = new EraseButtonListener();
        erase.addActionListener(eraselistener);

        OpenMenuListener openMenuListener = new OpenMenuListener();
        open.addActionListener(openMenuListener);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DrawingApplication frame = new DrawingApplication();
        frame.setTitle("My prgram");
        frame.setSize(400, 300);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Comment: `"doesnt send a feedback when i click the open button in my Gui "` -- I don't see an open "button" in the code above, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: This will not compile -- you are missing an import for java.awt.event.ActionListener.  Please use a SSCCE:  http://sscce.org/

Comment: when i run it, the Erase button spills outside the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem of name aliasing, you add the listener to the `open` variable which is declared as a `JMenuItem`, so you are adding the `ActionListener` to the menu item instead that to a button (that you never declare since there is no `JButton open = new JButton("open")` anywhere).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed i should have instanciate my object as MenuItem instead of Jmenu. Thank you